# How to modify a database column type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations

I am working on a `rails 5.1.6` web application which uses [Rateit](https://github.com/gjunge/rateit.js) as star rating jQuery plugin.

So I created a Review model to store the `Rateit` ratings in a column of `integer` type. 
However, since Rateit allows to choose half stars, I would like to change the rating column of the Review model from integer to float. According to [an article](https://tosbourn.com/rails-migrate-change-column-type/) I read, to modify a column in the database it is advised to create a new migration with the modification required, using the `change_column` method. 
Since I am a solo worker, my application is still in development environment, and the Review model still has to be committed, I wonder if I can, as alternative to the above solution, modify the existing migration changing `t.integer` into `t.float` and then run `$ rails db:migrate:reset` followed by `$ rails db:seed`.

Comment: You actually can since you did not commit your changes yet and also did not run it in any external environment like `staging` or `production`, I think it is always good to keep your modification history but you can rollback your state to the previous state from that migration, change it and migrate again.

Comment: As the above poster says - if you've not commited any migrations then you can simply rollback the last migration with `rake db:migrate:rollback`, edit the migration, and then rerun it.

Comment: Alternatively if other people may have run the migration, the safest option is always to write a second migration changing the column type